# Upper bound for the exponential integral Ei(x)

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I'm trying to find an upper bound for

$f(m, \alpha) := \frac{m\cdot \mathrm{Ei}(m(1-\alpha))}{\exp(m(1-\alpha))}$. Here $m \ge 1$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.

When I compute values of $f$, I see that $f(m, \alpha) \le \frac{2}{1-\alpha}$.

However, I cannot show this rigorously. Could you please help to obtain a tight upper bound? Thank you.

Comment: Are there restrictions on $\alpha$ or $m$? Seems like $\alpha < 1$?

Comment: Yes, $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Fixed.

Comment: You may find the asymptotic expansions helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral. The bounds for $E_1$ (which is similar, but not exactly the same is given). Some algebraic manipulation could help.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to showing that $\operatorname {Ei}(x) \leq 2 e^{x}/x$ when $x > 0$. The maximum of $\operatorname {Ei}(x) - 2 e^{x}/x$ is attained at $x = 2$ and is negative because
$$\operatorname {Ei}(2) <
\int_0^2 \frac {e^t - e^{-t}} t dt <
\int_0^2 \frac {e^2 - e^{-2}} 2 dt < e^2.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(m, \alpha)=m\frac{ \mathrm{Ei}(m(1-\alpha))}{\exp(m(1-\alpha))}$$ Let $x=m(1-\alpha)$ to make
$$g(x, \alpha)=\frac 1{1-\alpha}\, x\,\mathrm{Ei}(x) \,e^{-x}$$
The maximum value of $x\,\mathrm{Ei}(x) \,e^{-x}$ is a bit lower than $1.5$ ($1.4841$ to be precise). So
$$f(m, \alpha) \lt \frac {1.4841}{(1-\alpha)}$$

Comment: Thanks! Simple and concise.
Is it possible to find roots of $d(x \mathrm{Ei}(x)e^{-x})/dx = 0$ without numerical methods?

Comment: @rbtrht. THe value is $x=3.0657708258384584351$ and it looks to be extremely close to $10 \left(\text{Ei}(1)-\cot ^{-1}(2)\right) / \text{Feig1}$ $\text{Feig1}$ being the first Feigenbaum constant.